# Why is it called Movie 43?

Tags: title, movie-43

Why is it called [Movie 43](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Movie_43)?

I saw the movie more than once, but didn't find what the number 43 means.

Comment: Maybe it is [42](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phrases_from_The_Hitchhiker%27s_Guide_to_the_Galaxy#Answer_to_the_Ultimate_Question_of_Life.2C_the_Universe.2C_and_Everything_.2842.29) plus one?

Comment: You saw it more than once? The horror!  The ... horror!

Answer (score 12):

It means nothing. It was a random pick.

> The title of the film, Movie 43—first believed to be referencing the
>   number of actors in the film—actually has no meaning. Farrelly heard
>   his son talking with friends about a film called "Movie 43", but when
>   Farrelly discovered the film did not actually exist, he cribbed the
>   name

[Source](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Movie_43#Promotion)

I also found this

> Q: What exactly does the title, Movie 43, mean? A: According to
>   Wikipedia, the title references one of the sketches in the film where
>   a bunch of teenagers are surfing on the internet looking for a banned
>   movie called Movie 43. Apparently this has to do with the 43rd rule of
>   the Internet, which is that if you search long enough you will find
>   something.

[Source](http://scenecreek.com/movieqa/movie-43-qa/)

I'm looking and have found internet rules, but 43 isn't "search long enough and you will find something", instead it seems to be "The more beautiful and pure a thing is, the more satisfying it is to corrupt it."

Comment: I should occasionaly look up...;) It's also worth noting that there's a [framing sketch](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Movie_43#Alternative_version_.28The_Thread.29) in some countries about a banned movie called that, and the sketches appear on the 43rd search on the result list.

Comment: @Walt I originally had that in my first answer, but took it out since it didn't directly answer the question.

Comment: Also note we got most of this info from the exact same link the OP posted

Comment: Seeing as the "Movie 43" is banned and all, shouldn't that have been rule 34?

Comment: @Angew No, because Rule 34 is, "If it exists, there is porn of it." Rule 43 is a more general rule.